# Help for title!

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to think of a title for my Bachelor Thesis. You see, i use a lot of "of". "From" and "on" don't work.

Some ideas? Here's what I'm starting with:

Morphology of the ivory horns of Elephants

or
Functional and morphological Analysis on the ivory horns of Elephants

or

Functional morphology from the ivory horns of elephants?

which is the best?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *horn* or *tusk*?  Assuming the latter, you could go for a nominal compound:

> The morphology of elephant tusk ivory
>
> The functional morphology of elephant tusk ivory

(Concerning the other suggestions: *analysis of* sounds better than *analysis on* in this context. *morphology from ... tusks* doesn't really sound like you're describing tusks, I can't quite put my finger on why it sounds off though.)

Further thought: I appreciate that ivory can come from any dentine tissue, but wouldn't the assumption normally be that if you're talking about elephant ivory, then you're talking about tusks, not teeth?  If so, then you could forget about *tusk* and just go for:

> The morphology of elephant ivory
>
> The functional morphology of elephant ivory